# AngularJS and JAX-RS - Updating Table List after inserting model

Tags: angularjs, jax-rs

I am just starting to learn AngularJS from here:
http://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2014/02/26/angular-js-blog-series-table-of-content/

And I am currently at [chapter 5](http://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2013/12/17/angularjspart-5-pushing-data-to-the-server/), so I am not yet into promises, custom directives, etc. The REST Web service part of this tutorial is written in C#/.NET (of which I know nothing of, except for some similarity in Java) while I write my own Web Service in Java.

Here is my HTML:

```
<body ng-App="doctorApp">
    <div ng-controller="doctorCtrl">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>User Name</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="doctor in doctors" >
                    <td>{{doctor.lastName}}</td>
                    <td>{{doctor.firstName}}</td>
                    <td>{{doctor.user.userName}}</td>
                    <td>{{doctor.description}}</td>
            </tbody>
        </table>    
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="doctorCtrl">
        <h2>Add a Doctor</h2>
        <form class="myForm">
            <div>
                <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
                <input id="firstName" type="text" ng-model="firstName" /><br/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                <input id="lastName" type="text" ng-model="lastName" /><br/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="description">Description</label>
                <input id="description" type="text" ng-model="description" /><br/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="userName">User Name</label>
                <input id="userName" type="text" ng-model="userName" /><br/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" ng-model="password" /><br/>
            </div>
            <button ng-click="addDoctor()" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src='js/libs/angular.js/angular.js'></script>
    <script src='js/doctors.js'></script>
</body>
```

And here is my JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module("doctorApp", []);

app.controller("doctorCtrl", function($scope, $http) {

    loadDoctors();

    $scope.refresh = function() {
        loadDoctors();
    };

    function loadDoctors() {
        $http.get('localhost/myrestapi')
               .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.doctors = data;
                }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    // error
                });
    };

    $scope.addDoctor = function() {

        var currentDate = new Date();

        var data = {
            firstName: $scope.firstName,
            lastName: $scope.lastName,
            description: $scope.description,
            modifyDate: currentDate,
            user: {
                userName: $scope.userName,
                password: $scope.password,
                modifyDate: currentDate
            }
        };

        $http.post('localhost/myrestapi', data)
            .success(function(data, status, headers) {
                alert("Doctor added");
                // This is where I have my trouble, this section, copied from the tutorial 
                // is supposed to update/refresh my table list
                $http.get(headers("location"))
                    .success(function(data) {
                        $scope.doctors.push(data);
                    });
        });
    };

});
```

The author (Gabriel Schenker, thanks to your tutorial by the way) uses HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader (written in C#) in the web service side plus $http.get in the JavaScript/AngularJS side to update/refresh the list after an entry is inserted.

I can insert entries just fine (it shows in MySQL), the alert goes, but the new entry does not reflect on the list (at the view, invoking GET again is not (AJAX) wise, right?). Problem is, I am not aware of its counterpart or how to implement it in Java/JAX-RS (as I am not that in-depth in JAX-RS either). So my questions are:

1. How do I implement in Java the equivalent of C#'s HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader that responds to the section of the code (under the comment) above?
2. Even without implementing a JAX-RS counterpart in question 1, how do I do it in AngularJS so that it refreshes my list right away after insert?

I have already scoured the web, including here in stackoverflow, and there are many similar questions and solutions that uses advanced (for me right now) AngularJS concepts (like using scope.$apply(), $compile, modelFactory with $save, DOM manipulation with directives, etc.), however, I prefer to follow the tutorial to its end and I also want to see a solution that is most fitting to this situation and still uses $http.post.

Many thanks to those who can answer.

-Julius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about 1)

but for the Angular part

You view is bound to the model with the `ngRepeat` directive so you only need to add the newly created doctor to `$scope.doctors`.

Assuming your web service return the newly created doctor after the post response

you could do

```
       $http.post('localhost/myrestapi', data)
        .success(function(data, status, headers) {
            alert("Doctor added");
            $scope.doctors.push(data);
    });
```

The header *location* can be used for two reason see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location)

> The HTTP Location header field is returned in responses from an HTTP server under two circumstances:
>
> 1.To ask a web browser to load a different web page (URL redirection). In this circumstance, the Location header should be sent with an HTTP status code of 3xx. It is passed as part of the response by a web server when the requested URI has:
>   Moved temporarily;
>   Moved permanently; or
>
> 2.Processed a request, e.g. a POSTed form, and is providing the result of that request at a different URI
>   To provide information about the location of a newly created resource. In this circumstance, the Location header should be sent with an HTTP status code of 201 or 202.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location)

So in the case of your tutorial we are in the second case: the web service tells the client where to find the newly created resource so it can fetch it (this has to be implemented by your sever and I can not help you) ie by the http GET requet.

Another way to refresh you UI would be to get again the whole list of doctors calling `loadDoctors()` but this would be inefficient as it would use more bandwidth